# Super Simple Box Chart in Plotly for JS?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a blank space on my app, and I'd like to have a small box chart showing the basic distribution of a set of dollar amounts. Here's what my page looks like, and where I'd like the chart to fit:

[image]

I've searched Google, and found a few options, but they're all so complex. For instance, here's what Plotly gave me:

[image]

See how it's way larger than the space it's supposed to fill? Below is more what I'm looking for:

[image]

I'm not married to Plotly, I just want a simple box chart. No interactivity or anything fancy.

---

Here's my code on codepen: https://codepen.io/travisheeter/pen/Jjmayor, and the js is here for your reference:

```
var y0 = [525,784,674,453,241.6,532,662,465,636,508,345,29,526,476,1354.16,896.16,288.16,786,1445,870,731,521,835.16,1162.16,899.16,664.16,687.16,1896.16,1106.16,1106.16,808.16,938.16,808.16,545.16,778.16,1052.16,1274.16,125,125,125,905,822,842,706,900,369,447,361,404,514,529,913,717,806,557,1083,736,158,739,909,1108,243,584,650,427,603,603,650.16,776,933,489,789,863,779,610,1128,696,460,933,1,25,632,923,540,714,958,444,236.8,905,776,776,1000,776,584,662,770,703,817,871,793,870,776,840,695,951,905,863,589,858,533,731,589,692,410,301,170,382,243,259,420,398,364,704,612,379,279,305,213,347,368,215,295,693,770,714,618,425,484,656,896,943,683,454.16,535,524,548,732,782,725,106,596,790,656,594,496,713,883,805,718,664,836,529,677,708,884,645,1401.16,736,669,898,370,832,668,952,1066,775,1,1006,776,756,776,705,698,618,776,1242,291,905,776,754,798,713,655,811,295,840,595,613,489,851,770,740,569,474,702,414,776,743,986,767,713,665,812,827,213,716,681,675,257,665,831,223,720.16,2312.16,233,721,696]

var trace1 = {
  x: y0,
  type: 'box'
};

var data = [trace1];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

---

Update: Here's a new Pen updated to show the constraints and adding @0stone0's answer: https://codepen.io/travisheeter/pen/MWPqEvX

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by forcing the graph div to expand/shrink according to its container (ie. so that the autosize matches the room left by the `.col-sm` flex item) :

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
```

And in the layout, just remove the margins :

```js
const layout  = {
  autosize: true,
  margin: {
    t: 0, 
    b: 0, 
    l: 0, 
    r: 0
  }
};
```

Output :

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the `staticPlot` option to disable all fancy hover things:

```
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, {}, { staticPlot: true, responsive: true });
```

I've also added `responsive` should you page resize.

The width/height can be changed using the `width` and `height` prop in the `layout` object
https://plotly.com/javascript/setting-graph-size/

---

```js
var y0 = [525,784,674,453,241.6,532,662,465,636,508,345,29,526,476,1354.16,896.16,288.16,786,1445,870,731,521,835.16,1162.16,899.16,664.16,687.16,1896.16,1106.16,1106.16,808.16,938.16,808.16,545.16,778.16,1052.16,1274.16,125,125,125,905,822,842,706,900,369,447,361,404,514,529,913,717,806,557,1083,736,158,739,909,1108,243,584,650,427,603,603,650.16,776,933,489,789,863,779,610,1128,696,460,933,1,25,632,923,540,714,958,444,236.8,905,776,776,1000,776,584,662,770,703,817,871,793,870,776,840,695,951,905,863,589,858,533,731,589,692,410,301,170,382,243,259,420,398,364,704,612,379,279,305,213,347,368,215,295,693,770,714,618,425,484,656,896,943,683,454.16,535,524,548,732,782,725,106,596,790,656,594,496,713,883,805,718,664,836,529,677,708,884,645,1401.16,736,669,898,370,832,668,952,1066,775,1,1006,776,756,776,705,698,618,776,1242,291,905,776,754,798,713,655,811,295,840,595,613,489,851,770,740,569,474,702,414,776,743,986,767,713,665,812,827,213,716,681,675,257,665,831,223,720.16,2312.16,233,721,696]

var trace1 = {
  x: y0,
  type: 'box'
};

var data = [trace1];

const layout  = { autosize: false, width: 300, height: 200 };
const options = { staticPlot: true, responsive: true };

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.20.0.min.js"></script>

<div id='myDiv'>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I updated my CodePen to include the bootstrap configuration present on my real page. I've tried to adjust the Plotly width to fit there, but it seems to only accept whole numbers. Is that true?

Comment: Here's a Pen with your answer and me trying to use a % for width: https://codepen.io/travisheeter/pen/MWPqEvX

Comment: Seems like only pixels are supported. You could use some JS to trigger a resize, so the `autosize` will make it fit. Or just some JS to get the width of the div, and apply that to the `layout'.